# Root filesystem usage at 100%, but I can't see why

Tags: filesystem

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 with Jessie.

`df` shows 100% usage on `/`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ df -h .
S.ficheros     Tamaño Usados  Disp Uso% Montado en
/dev/root         15G    14G   44M 100% /
```

But if I search I can't see why it is full (at `home` an external 2 TB hard drive is mounted):

```
. 757,4GiB [##########] /home
    2,5GiB [          ] /usr
  348,1MiB [          ] /lib
. 261,3MiB [          ] /var
  147,4MiB [          ] /opt
   20,7MiB [          ] /boot
   20,1MiB [          ] /boot.bak
.  15,0MiB [          ] /etc
    8,0MiB [          ] /bin
    7,6MiB [          ] /sbin
. 700,0KiB [          ] /run
.  64,0KiB [          ] /tmp
!  16,0KiB [          ] /lost+found
    8,0KiB [          ] /media
e   4,0KiB [          ] /srv
!   4,0KiB [          ] /root
e   4,0KiB [          ] /mnt
.   0,0  B [          ] /sys
.   0,0  B [          ] /proc
    0,0  B [          ] /dev
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you show us `df -h` output?

Comment: I put the output above to can see better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo du -h / --exclude /home | grep -P "^[\d\.]+M|G\s+" > du-rootfs.txt
```

That will take a few minutes, but give you more details about what's taking up all the space.  You'll find a list of directories with sizes in `du-rootfs.txt`.

This should skip examining the "home" directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you've been regularly updating your system, `/var/cache/apt/archives` will have a lot of cached packages in it.

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

will clear them out, and likely give you enough space to keep the system running.

Comment: I would primarily suspect such a thing too but the OP's list shows that `/var` does not seem to be the issue here.